# Bootstrap sandwich nav unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap framework to build a site and the responsive navigation works fine in the live demo but when I try and insert it into my code it becomes unresponsive and I cannot tell why?

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Café Névé</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/creative.css" type="text/css">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="50">

<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Café Névé</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

<div class="header alt vert">
  <div class="container">

    <h1 id='topheader'>Café Névé

      <p class="lead"><img src='img/snowflake.png'></p></h1>
  </div>


<div id="sec1" class="blurb">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h1 id='who'>Who We Are</h1>
        <p class="lead"><!--The Most Popular Responsive Framework--></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <h1 class="pull-right"><i class="icon-mobile-phone icon-3x"></i> <i class="icon-tablet icon-3x"></i> <i class="icon-laptop icon-3x"></i></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="featurette" id="sec2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
       <!-- <h1>Amazing Features</h1> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <i class="icon-rocket"></i>
          <h4>Mission</h4>
          <p>Words we live by</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <i class="icon-magnet"></i>
          <h4>History</h4>
          <p>Where we came from</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <i class="icon-shield"></i>
          <h4>Source</h4>
          <p>What we brew and why</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
          <h4>Retailers</h4>
          <p>Where you can get our coffee</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="callout" id="sec3">
  <div class="vert">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>RACHEL LOCATION</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="callout" id="sec4">
  <div class="vert">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>MILE END LOCATION</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="callout" id="sec5">
  <div class="vert">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>STANLEY LOCATION</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="callout" id="sec6">
  <div class="vert">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>TORONTO LOCATION</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="blurb bright">

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        <h3>Founding Partners</h3>
        <br>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h2><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Luke</h2></div>
         <div class="panel-body text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
          Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
          dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
          Aliquam in felis si.

          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h2>Gabe <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></h2></div>
         <div class="panel-body text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
          Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
          dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
          Aliquam in felis sit.



          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--
<div class="blurb">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        <h3>Sharing the Bootstrap Love</h3>
        <p class="lead"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li><i class="icon-facebook icon-2x"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-twitter icon-2x"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-google-plus icon-2x"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-pinterest icon-2x"></i></li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <p>Built with <i class="icon-heart-empty"></i> at <a href="http://www.bootply.com">Bootply</a>.<br>Company ©2014</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<ul class="nav pull-right scroll-down">
  <li><a href="#" title="Scroll down"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-3x"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav pull-right scroll-top">
  <li><a href="#" title="Scroll to top"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-3x"></i></a></li>
</ul>-->

    <!-- script references -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its better to show this as a fiddle or codepen example so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me,looks like your script link to jQuery CDN is missing the http: part

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/QjmyWP)

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Café Névé</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" id="myNav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```